# Nice text formatting in QTextEdit, like Qt Creator does

Tags: qt

[Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) spots a nice formatting operation, drawing a thin frame around some text (here an example, I refer to the frames around addRow, the yellow areas were the result a text find operation that also had framed the locations found, before I moved the cursor..)

[image]

I've been unable to find how to get that effect in QTextEdit. I tried to read from Qt Creator sources, but they are too large for uninformed search...

*edit*

I started just now to look into custom QTextCharAttribute, via

```
class framedTextAttr : public QTextObjectInterface {...}
```

*edit*

It's working: as per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19425572/874024) below.

Comment: Not sure how much usefull this link will be. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-codeeditor.html

Comment: Thanks, @Tab, I'm aware of that example. Could be that there is no ready to reuse effect apart pushing custom painting and keeping tracks of the areas. But it would complicate the code and it's difficult to see how to make that reusable.

Comment: QtCreator uses a custom editor widget. There's no way to implement this without writing code that does custom painting, of course. A proper answer would require some reverse-engineering of `QTextEdit`'s implementation to find a code-minimal way of doing it. I suggest you bump up the bounty :)

Comment: What you see is not a brush, it's a shape that has both a brush, a pen, and geometry.

Comment: @KubaOber: well, these 2 comments together could be a better response than seen so far. Why don't you post your answer ?

Comment: The extra selections feature of QTextEdit Can be used to create similar effect. Though it probably can't create a border around the highlight.

Comment: @CapelliC if this turns out to be what you are after, and want an answer to accept, I can write short answer tonight and edit it with example code in a few days... I've used it for breakpoints and highlighting matching braces, at least.

Comment: @hyde: you're welcome, post a short answer. by now I have no idea about what do you mean. Now I'm going with QTextObjectInterface...

Comment: Here is an idea, why don't you try doing it with a standalone overlay object? Just map it to the coordinates of what you need to highlight and paint it as you wish.

Comment: @ddriver: thanks. Actually, I'm going to use that architecture for something more complex than character formatting, but related - QTextEdit it's an (almost) full HTML editor. The nicest I ever seen so far !

Comment: That's Qt for you, an awful lot of functionality out of the box, but still designed rather inflexible in many aspects. Sometimes it is very hard to integrate a custom feature with stock components.

Comment: @ddriver: to me, it's surely more interesting than MFC. I think it's keeping C++ alive, really. Qt give C++ a **true** GUI system.

Comment: @CapelliC - not really, Qt has given up on C++ when it comes to UI, the last 4 years 99% of the development efforts are focused on QML. Widgets are already marked as a "done" module, they are just kept for backwards compatibility and are not actively developed, at best critical bugs will be resolved, but that's about it.

Comment: @ddriver: I don't fully agree: see how much effort has been put in enhancing the QGraphicScene architecture, or the advancement in QWebEngine (prototypical now). Of course C++ can be a *better* language than Javascript on *some* task. For instance, where you have C++ open source code to reuse directly, like ... well, some thousand of projects...

Comment: I was not discussing the merits of different programming languages, just mentioned that Qt is moving away from C++ when it comes to GUI. I accent on GUI, which is widgets, QGS is more suited to custom graphics inside the GUI, but is very slow to work with compared to QML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With QTextObjectInterface I get the frame around the text object:

```
QSizeF framedTextAttr::intrinsicSize(QTextDocument *doc, int posInDocument, const QTextFormat &format)
{
    Q_ASSERT(format.type() == format.CharFormat);
    const QTextCharFormat &tf = *(const QTextCharFormat*)(&format);
    QString s = format.property(prop()).toString();
    QFont fn = tf.font();
    QFontMetrics fm(fn);
    return fm.boundingRect(s).size();
}

void framedTextAttr::drawObject(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect, QTextDocument *doc, int posInDocument, const QTextFormat &format)
{
    Q_ASSERT(format.type() == format.CharFormat);
    QString s = format.property(prop()).toString();
    painter->drawText(rect, s);
    painter->drawRoundedRect(rect, 2, 2);
}
```

But the text becomes a single object, no more editable

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setCentralWidget(new QTextEdit);

    framedTextAttr *fa = new framedTextAttr;
    editor()->document()->documentLayout()->registerHandler(framedTextAttr::type(), fa);

    editor()->setPlainText("hic sunt\n leones !");

    QTextCharFormat f;
    f.setObjectType(fa->type());

    QTextCursor c = editor()->document()->find("leones");
    f.setProperty(fa->prop(), c.selectedText());

    c.insertText(QString(QChar::ObjectReplacementCharacter), f);
}
```

And the result (here a picture):

[image]

It seems it's difficult to generalize. I'm not satisfied...

*edit*

Actually, it's feasible.
I've worked out some of the problems with the illustrated approach, and it seems to be viable also for *folding/unfolding* text in reusable fashion.

[image]

I've put [my test project on GitHub](https://github.com/CapelliC/foldingQTextEdit).

Answer (score 12):

Use [`QTextEdit::setExtraSelections()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#setExtraSelections) to highlight any arbitrary sections of the document. [*QTextEdit::ExtraSelection* class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtextedit-extraselection.html) is simple class with public member variables, used to define each highlight. To create a highlight,

1. get `QTextCursor` from the `QTextEdit`
2. manipulate the cursor so that it contains the right text as selection
3. store cursor and desired `QTextCharFormat` in an `ExtraSelections` object (just assign values, no need for pointers or `new`)
4. store the `ExtraSelections` object (as value) in `QList`
5. repeat above for all highlights you want
6. call the `setExtraSelections()` method

Some example code:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // create QTextEdit, with lot of text in it
    QTextEdit w("Alice and Bob (and Eve). ");
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i) w.setText(w.toPlainText() + w.toPlainText());

    // prepare variables for highlights
    QTextCharFormat fmt;
    fmt.setUnderlineStyle(QTextCharFormat::SingleUnderline);
    fmt.setUnderlineColor(QColor(200,200,200));
    fmt.setBackground(QBrush(QColor(230,230,230)));

    // highlight all text in parenthesis
    QTextCursor cursor = w.textCursor();
    while( !(cursor = w.document()->find(QRegExp("\\([^)]*\\)"), cursor)).isNull()) {
        QTextEdit::ExtraSelection sel = { cursor, fmt };
        selections.append(sel);
    }

    // set, show, go!
    w.setExtraSelections(selections);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks, that will be useful in another part (find/replace) I'm working on. Sadly is not related directly to drawing what's selected. that was my question...

Comment: Can't check right now, but there may be easy methods to get screen coordinates for text cursors, and related row heights etc. If so, then overriding paintEvent and drawing extra semitransparent lines on top after base class painting might be a way to get the desired visual effect without too much code.

Comment: @CapelliC Pasted some example code, and just now tweaked it to to do about 25% of the visual effect you want ;). One way for full effect might be to search where the `QTextCharFormat` is actually applied, and the underline drawn. Then either copy code to your own application and change it, or if you're really lucky, subclassing `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout` might work.

Comment: thanks, but I'm already making an **advanced** use of dynamic text formatting - I'm working a SWI-Prolog IDE. See my answer for more explanation to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CapelliC Yeah, no problem, I still wanted to complete the answer to the state I originally intended (with code snippet)

Answer (score 1):

Is using `QTextEdit` a requirement? If not, you can use [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org) as the text editing component, which has a Qt binding. Scintilla has the [Indicator](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Indicators) feature which does exactly what you want.

Comment: and of course, I'm still far from completion of my target, exploring the awesome capability of QTextEdit. I'm not interested in Scintilla...

Answer (score 0):

You can check out syntaxhighlighter example for Qt Code.I guess it will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Well, using part of code of a big projects like Qt Creator is not easy at all, and it could take more time and effort than creating your own code from scratch.

For your problem, Qt has a cool class [`QSyntaxHighlighter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) that you can inherit and set your syntax patterns as regular expressions and rules (color, font weight, ...)

So for your case, you need to set the syntax patterns dynamically when user types in the find box or when selecting a word, and for the syntax rule it will be background color.

Comment: I'm actually using QSyntaxHighlighter, but it has little to do with my question, that's about a *specific* graphic formatting of text. Some kind of a specialized QBrush, but I can't find the right bits...

Comment: My point is, you can get this same effect with QSyntaxHighlighter, if you need a detailed answer with code snipped, let me know, and I will edit the answer.

Comment: No, you can't get that effect, QSyntaxHighlighter it's actually irrilevant here. More relevant is the code hinted by Tab, in comment above.

Comment: @CapelliC, please look at my (similar) question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349138/how-to-draw-line-between-folded-blocks-in-qplaintextedit